# Присвоение значения переменной при нажатии кнопки диалогового окна в android приложение

Tags: java, android, асинхронность

Подскажите пожалуйста, есть android приложения в котором пользователю задают вопрос и в зависимости от ответа надо получить boolean переменную с значением true или false. Так же эта переменная должна быть доступна вне диалогового окна для обработки результата.

P.S. в логе в не зависимости от нажатой кнопки выводится false

```
final boolean[] a=new boolean[1];
                    new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
                            .setTitle("Вы хотите сохранить ключ?")
                            .setMessage("Вы хотите сохранить ключ? Вся ранее используемая переписка будет потеряна. В случае отказа будет использован ведённый ключ, но переписка которую вы ведёте сэтим ключом будет потеряна")
                            .setNegativeButton(android.R.string.no, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN)
                                public void onClick(DialogInterface arg0, int arg1) {
                                    a[0] =false;
                                }
                            })
                            .setPositiveButton(android.R.string.yes, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN)
                                public void onClick(DialogInterface arg2, int arg3) {
                                    a[0] =true;
                                }
                            }).create().show();
                    Log.i(TAG, "aaaaaaaaaaaaa=" + a[0]);
```

Comment: Вы в лог выведите время отображения данных и время нажатия на кнопки, и все поймете сразу :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

При обработке нажатия кнопки это происходит в другом потоке, в нем и нужно производить манипуляции:

```
 .setPositiveButton(android.R.string.yes, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN)
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface arg2, int arg3) {
                                deleteKeyAction();
                            }
                        })
```